# Shutdown Access is Denied (5)

Tags: windows-7, remote-access, remote-shutdown

This is a bit different, so not a duplicate of the other question.

I heard that you need access to the computer that you want to shut down remotely but doing
`net use \\remcomp\IPC$ password /USER:user`

Source: http://www.squidworks.net/2011/07/how-to-pass-a-username-and-password-to-windows-shutdown-exe-command/

But that does not work:

`C:\Users\*****>net use \\***********-** \IPC$ *********************** /USER:"**** ******"
The command completed successfully.
C:\Users\*****>shutdown -s -m \\***********-**
***********-**: Access is denied.(5)`

Why is that so?

I can understand this question is short on info, but tell me what other information I may need to give to you guys. This is not the same computer I talked about in my last question however, the remote computer is.

Comment: Is the user granted remote shutdown privileges?

Comment: @and31415 It should be. But appears not.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Microsoft PSTools specifically the psshutdown to shutdown computers in your network.

Comment: I'll make sure to look into this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you get an 'access denied' error when attempting to shut down, log off or reboot a Windows system from Device ManageR, first manually test whether Device ManageR's host system can shut down the target computer; then, if it can, run Device Manager as an administrator with the host system's username and password.